# SQL Server random rows on where clause

Tags: sql-server, random

I need to select 10 random rows from a table, but it has to be done in the where clause, because the query is executed using another aplication that only allows to modify this part.

I searched for a lot of solutions (`select top 10`, `RAND()`, `ORDER BY NEWID()`, ...), but none work in the where clause.

There an option to do that? or some kind of workaround?

Comment: Why not just get the result from the app and make it random in your program logic?

Comment: Because the program basically shows the table with all rows, and only allows some basic filters (sorting and filtering by content) and then an option to add a where clausule.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT TOP 10 Id FROM Test ORDER BY NewId())
```

Answer (score 1):

If your table has a unique column you can do something like :

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PRIMARYCOLUMN IN (SELECT TOP(10) PRIMARYCOLUMN FROM TABLE ORDER BY NEWID())`